# Guidelines regarding spaces for class variables, instance variables, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a guideline to follow in regard to space for class variables, instance variables, etc? For example

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :something
  has_many: :something_elses
  validates: :property, presence: true
  after_save :do_something
end
```

In this case I'm using as example a model record, but I would like to understand the standard style for everything. I'm using Rubocop and it doesn't tell me anything about this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm also interested in `include` and `extend`.

Comment: It's in the Rubocop style guide, you can't miss it: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#consistent-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[anothermh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3784008/anothermh) shared the link above (and for the record, amazing that their profile photo is of Robocop when this question is about Rubocop) ... but here's what the [Rubocop guidelines for classes](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#consistent-classes) suggest:

```rb
class Person
  # extend and include go first
  extend SomeModule
  include AnotherModule

  # inner classes
  CustomError = Class.new(StandardError)

  # constants are next
  SOME_CONSTANT = 20

  # afterwards we have attribute macros
  attr_reader :name

  # followed by other macros (if any)
  validates :name

  # public class methods are next in line
  def self.some_method
  end

  # initialization goes between class methods and other instance methods
  def initialize
  end

  # followed by other public instance methods
  def some_method
  end

  # protected and private methods are grouped near the end
  protected

  def some_protected_method
  end

  private

  def some_private_method
  end
end
```

As a personal note: although having consistent styling makes it quicker and easier to read code and for others to scan what you're written, keep in mind that these are just *recommendations* of "best practices". At the end of the day whatever works best FOR YOU should be *your* new best practice.